# Instanced Objects Not Rotating When Mirrored

Tags: mirror, instances

After instancing an object to the vertices of a line, when I apply a mirror modifier to that line (in this case, around an axis), the orientation of the instances does not rotate when mirrored (the mirrored instances are all facing the same direction as the original instances).

I was told that using instancing with faces instead of vertices should cause the new mirrored instances to follow the normals of the mirrored faces.  Instead, the orientation remains the same.  Rotating the faces and recalculating the normals to Outside does not fix the issue.  Can anyone please advise the best way to allow the mirrored instances to be properly rotated?

**Instancing Using Vertices**

[image]

**Instancing Using Faces**

[image]

Comment: yes, it would be interesting to know why it behaves this way, that said what you could do to mirror is select both object and faces, then alt D to duplicate, and S X -1 (if you want to mirror on the X axis)